# No instance for (Num[Int]) arising from the literal `3'

Tags: haskell

I started learning Haskell today. I know some basics of C++, C#, but I'm a beginner programmer.

I wrote the following in a file "file.hs":

```
exampleList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
exRange2 = [2*x | x <- [exampleList], (x `mod` 3) /= 1]
```

When I input

```
:l file
```

into my GHCi console, it gives me the error:

```
functions1.hs:20:47:
    No instance for (Num [Int]) arising from the literal `3'
    In the second argument of `mod', namely `3'
    In the first argument of `(/=)', namely `(x `mod` 3)'
    In the expression: (x `mod` 3) /= 1
Failed, modules loaded: none
```

Note it looks like it interchangably uses gravises and apostrophes. I don't understand what's wrong.

My quick excursion into Google convinced me it was an issue with types of both arguments of mod, but shouldn't the compiler know that all `x`s are going to be integers if it has the exampleList defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Screenshots of code or errors are bad.  Copy and paste the text instead.

Short answer:  `exampleList` is already a list.  By putting it in `[]`, you make it a list of lists.  Don't do that.

Long answer: GHC tries as hard as it can to make sense of what you wrote.  It needs `exampleList` and `3` to have the same type for the type of `mod` to work.  Since numeric constants are polymorphic in Haskell, it says:

> Ah, this code works when there is a way to make a list out of a numeric
>   literal. I just need to find the instance of `Num` in use.  Wait,
>   there isn't one.  Error time!